# Why does this css not space the elements the way I want?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a table which I want to have a top part, middle part, and a bottom part. The middle is also divided into a left, center, and right. I want it so that the only thing that ever gets larger or smaller is the middle's center. I am encountering a few problems with this however:

1. The table isn't filling the entire height;
2. The Center-Left and Center-Right aren't holding their widths

I have created a JsFiddle so that you can see what I mean.

http://jsfiddle.net/CGv2Z/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the fact that this is a table and you appear to be wanting to use it for layout (hint: You probably shouldn't be), and some other problems.

There were 2 primary problems.

1. You had every element under .Window set to display: block; and width: 100%. Remove that.
2. You have the width of .Window-Content-Content set to 100%, which is 100% of it's parent, which isn't what you want. You have left and right set to specific widths, table cells will then naturally fill in the extra width. if the parent table has a width set on it.

http://jsfiddle.net/CGv2Z/10/

Comment: Im fairly ignorant of positioning in html, so can you please explain a bit further why those changes are necessary? 1. I thought that css in children take precedence over generic rules like that. 2. Doesnt the 100% mean to take up 100% of the available space? (Obviously not, but can you please explain?) Also, how then do I get the resizing trait that I want?

Comment: @chacham15 As far as 100%, [read this](http://www.impressivewebs.com/width-100-percent-css/). If you want it resizing, then change the width and height of .Window. 100% is not what you think, it's always of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this :

http://jsfiddle.net/CGv2Z/12/